# Freeze summaryRow in nattable

Tags: nattable

I have requirement to aggregate few columns value in summary row of nattable which I was able to do using summary_provider, but problem is that row is not visible all the time and I have to scroll till the end to see aggregate value.

Is there any way to freeze summary row?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a layer composition with a `FixedSummaryRowLayer` like shown here https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_120.php

How such a composition would look like depends on your already existing layer composition, whether you have a grid or a simple table layout. But both cases are explained in that link and you find examples in the [NatTable Examples Application](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=examples_application)